# How Do I Add Keyboard Support For My Game?

Tags: java, keyboard, pong

I have been trying to make a Pong clone as sort of a beginner's project, and I've hit a road block. I have tried various methods to implement keyboard support, but none have worked.

For reference here is my Pong.java(the main class): http://pastebin.com/8d7BqK4x

Here is the Board.java(Graphics): http://pastebin.com/N9fLMzFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some general advice, you can add keyboard listeners and then interpret the input, here's a link with some advice on keyboard listeners: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html. For a game, I recommend using a "key pressed" event.

Comment: Awesome. The problem is that there is an initial delay when you hold down the key (it will fire once, stop for a little bit, then keep going, like when you're typing). How do I get rid of this?

Comment: I'm sorry can you clarify? Do you mean if you hold down l for 10 seconds you want it to register 1 l or 30 l's?

Comment: You can try key released, that may help your issue.